# Adding ThirdPartySetting to webform entity results in wrong module dependency

Tags: 8, webforms

I added my ThirdPartySetting to webform element like this:

Added my config schema to file `config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml` like this:

```
webform.settings.third_party.mymodule:
  type: mapping
  label: 'Webform mymodule configuration'
  mapping:
    settings:
      type: mapping
      label: 'mymodule settings'
      mapping:
        email_element:
          type: string
          label: 'E-mail element'
```

and then in `mymodule.module` I've altered webform settings form like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'webform_settings_form') {
    $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $elements = $entity->getElementsInitializedAndFlattened();
    $options = [];
    foreach ($elements as $element_name => $element) {
      $options[$element_name] = $element['#title'];
    }
    $form['third_party_settings']['email_element'] = [
      '#type' => 'details',
      '#title' => t('E-mail element'),
      '#open' => TRUE,
    ];
    $form['third_party_settings']['email_element']['email_element'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#title' => t('E-mail element'),
      '#default_value' => $entity->getThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'email_element'),
    ];
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_mymodule_form_submit';
  }
}

function _mymodule_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformInterface $entity */
  if ($entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()) {
    $entity->setThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'email_element', $form_state->getValue(['third_party_settings','email_element','email_element']));
    $entity->save();
  }
}
```

This works fine, but when I export my configuration, I see that dummy module has been added to my module dependencies.

```
 dependencies:
   module:
+    - mymodule
+    - email_element
```

This also reflects in `third_party_settings`

```
+third_party_settings:
+  email_element:
+    email_element: e_mail
+  mymodule:
+    email_element: e_mail
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @baikho is almost correct. In the end this worked for me:

```php
function mymodule_webform_third_party_settings_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformInterface $webform */
  $webform = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  $elements = $webform->getElementsInitializedAndFlattened();
  $options = [];
  foreach ($elements as $element_name => $element) {
    $options[$element_name] = $element['#title'];
  }

  $form['third_party_settings']['mymodule'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => t('My module'),
    '#open' => TRUE,
  ];

  $form['third_party_settings']['mymodule']['email_element'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#title' => t('E-mail element'),
    '#default_value' => $webform->getThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'email_element'),
  ];
}
```

And warning for anyone finding this in the future - if you do it wrong like I did, just download your database from another environment and start again, otherwise you might end up pulling your hair.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `hook_webform_third_party_settings_form_alter()` in `mymodule.module` and discard the submit handler which should solve that:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_webform_third_party_settings_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_webform_third_party_settings_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformInterface $webform */
  $webform = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

  // Do stuff.

  $form['third_party_settings']['email_element'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#title' => t('E-mail element'),
    '#default_value' => $webform->getThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'email_element'),
  ];

  // Do not add submit handler.
}
```

Webform's `WebformThirdPartySettingsManagerInterface` wraps Core's `ThirdPartySettingsInterface` which is why I think you're seeing that behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Adding select element like this leads to warning: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Drupal\webform\EntitySettings\WebformEntitySettingsGeneralForm->save() (line 549 of modules/contrib/webform/src/EntitySettings/WebformEntitySettingsGeneralForm.php).` If I wrap it in details element, there's no error, but the settings isn't saved. I also tried to use `\Drupal::service('webform.third_party_settings_manager');` as used in `honeypot_webform_third_party_settings_form_alter()`, but that didn't help.